# Extract html input with php

Tags: php, html

I am new to php and want to make a dropdown menu where you can select a site that you want, then when you click a button you will be redirected to that site. The button will take you to for example "google.com" if that is what you select, if you select "stackoverflow.com" the same button will take you there. I currently have no working php code as I am not sure where to start. I will include the html code below.

```
<form method="post" action="testttt.php">
<select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">  
    <option value="SelectSite"> Select Site Please
    <option value="Itslearning"> Itslearning
    <option value="NDLA"> NDLA
</select>

    <input type="submit" value="GO"/>
```

The form ends a bit further down, so please don't complain about there being no  :P ANY HELP IS APPRECIATED :)

Comment: Start by learning PHP, then write some PHP. This is not a difficult thing to achieve even with the basics.

Comment: i know some php, but i cant seem to find a way to accomplish this..

Comment: [header()](http://php.net/header) will point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, ill be looking in to it :)

Comment: Doesn't even need PHP... or a button for that matter - JavaScript `onchange` > `document.location` would do it.

Comment: i used a similar method at first, but i was quickly told that i cant do it with javascript.. wont it just take you to one site no matter what you select? (i might have been misinformed)

Comment: ^ Whoever told you that was wrong - just put the URLs into the option values (as Manthan Dave did in his answer) and then in your JS `myFunction()` just do something like `var sel = document.getElementById('mySelect'); document.location = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;` - would probably need a sanity check for the "select site please" option... but other than that it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code , i have done the example which you want and its work perfectly . You can do it this in single file as i have done .

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit']))
{

    $options = $_POST["testing"];
    header('Location: '.$options.'');
    echo "Your option value".$options;
}

?>
<form method="post" action="#">
<select id="mySelect" name="testing" onchange="myFunction()">  
    <option value="SelectSite"> Select Site Please
    <option value="http://www.google.com"> Itslearning
    <option value="http://www.stackoverflow.com"> NDLA
</select>

    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

- testttt.php will receive values in the $_POST array, so things like 'echo $_POST["somefield"];' will get you data...
- ...BUT you have to name your form elements.  Not '<select id="somefield"...' but '<select name="somefield"...'.  you can still have id attributes if you want, but pass to $_POST happens by what you put in the name= attribute.
- Once you know the URL you're redirecting to, header("Location: $url");

Hope that gives you the push you need :-)

Comment: this might explain why it didnt work when i tried using $_POST.... thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 0):

can you not just use the `myfunction` function like this:

```
function myfunction(event){
    return window.open(event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].value,'');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in php, your select need a name attribute :

```
<form method="post" action="testttt.php">
    <select id="mySelect" name="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">  
        <option value="SelectSite"> Select Site Please
        <option value="Itslearning"> Itslearning
        <option value="NDLA"> NDLA
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="GO"/>
</form>
```

You can do that either in PHP :

```
if(isset($_POST['mySelect']) && !empty($_POST['mySelect'])){
    header('Location: ' . $_POST['mySelect']);
}
```

Or in Javascript using the onchange attribute you already set up :

```
myFunction(){
    var target = event.target;
    document.location.href(target.options[target.options.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it with javascript at first, but i think ill be doing it in php as id like to learn more about it. Thanks for the input :9